# UIView to UIImage with layer borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a UIView whose layer has two sublayers, each of which has a 1.5 pixel border around the outside.  I am trying to create a UIImage from this view with the following code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

The code does return a UIImage, but the image is clipped – that is, the image doesn't include the all of the borders on the sublayers.  I've tried tweaking the sizes/bounds but to no effect.  Any suggestions of what else I might try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you send the parent **layer** a 
drawInContext: message instead of telling the view to draw itself?